# laravel phpunit test with api token authentication

Tags: laravel, phpunit

How can I add the authorization header in phpunit? I am testing a json api that requires an api_token. laravel docs provide a actingAs method. But this does not work in my case because the api token is not directly related to the users table.

EDIT:

```
public function test_returns_response_with_valid_request()
    {
        $response = $this->json('post', '/api/lookup', [
            'email' => 'user@gmail.com'
        ]);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertJsonStructure([
            'info' => [
                'name'
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 33):

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#session-and-authentication).

> You may also specify which guard should be used to authenticate the given user by passing the guard name as the second argument to the `actingAs` method:
>
> ```
> $this->actingAs($user, 'api');
> ```

Answer (score 10):

You can use withHeader method and pass in your token, and this works on my local (Laravel 6)

```
public function test_returns_response_with_valid_request()
{
    // define your $token here
    $response = $this->withHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token)
        ->json('post', '/api/lookup', [
            'email' => 'user@gmail.com'
        ]);

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertJsonStructure([
        'info' => [
            'name'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Or you can use actingAs with look at [docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication) with api guard

```
public function test_returns_response_with_valid_request()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $response = $this->actingAs($user, 'api')
        ->json('post', '/api/lookup', [
            'email' => 'user@gmail.com'
        ]);

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertJsonStructure([
        'info' => [
            'name'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#session-and-authentication)

```
public function test_returns_response_with_valid_request()
{
     $user = factory(User::class)->create();

     $response = $this->actingAs($user)
         ->post('/api/lookup',[
             'email' => 'user@gmail.com'
         ]);

     $response->assertStatus(200);
     $response->assertJsonStructure([
             'info' => [
                 'name'
             ]
         ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentations
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests & https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests

There are several ways of passing the API token to your application.
You may choose any of these approaches based on the needs of your application.

- **(Query String)** you may specify the token as an *api_token* query string value

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/api/sth?api_token='.$token, $test_data)->assertSussessful();
```

- **(Request Payload)** you may include the token in the request's form parameters as an *api_token*

```
     $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/sth', [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'api_token' => $token,
            ],
        ]);
```

- **(Bearer token)** Bearer token in the Authorization header of the request:

```
    $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/sth', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $token,
                    'Accept' => 'application/json'
                ]
            ]);
```

- **(Bearer token)** you can use *withHeaders* method and *Bearer* token in the Authorization header of the request:

```
    $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $token,
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ])->post('/api/sth', $test_data);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you. Also, sum up your answer in case the link stops working in the future.

Comment: I wanted to pass a token in request,
Consumers can communicate with api after getting a token.
In my test code, when I'm calling to the get/post/... api with authentication token, there was a problem.
If someone meets like this problem that can't pass a token to request, please read and follow the above doc;