# Data Not Found Hit API of Unit Testing Laravel 8.x

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-8, bearer-token

I'm new to working on backend to make a unit testing of index method with Bearer Token for authentication.

But, I got failure after I run the command : `.\vendor\bin\phpunit` like below :

```
PHPUnit 9.5.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..F                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)

Time: 00:00.228, Memory: 24.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\UserControllerTest::test_returns_user_data_list_successfully
Expected response status code [200] but received 404.

The following errors occurred during the request:

{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Failed",
    "error_code": 4041,
    "errors": {
        "message": "Data not found"
    }
}

Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404.

C:\Users\artha\Documents\Switch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse.php:177
C:\Users\artha\Documents\Switch\tests\Feature\UserControllerTest.php:18
```

For UserContoller.php :

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth.jwt');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->all();
        $message = 'Success';
        return $this->sendResponse($user->makeVisible('role'), $message, 200);
    }
}
```

The code of `route/api.php` :

```
Route::resource('user', UserController::class, ['except' => ['create', 'edit']]);
```

And I made `UserContollerTest.php` like below :

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class UserControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_returns_user_data_list_successfully()
    {
        $token    = 'eyJ0eXA.....dY3CtVO1T4o--8nM';
        $response = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $token,
                        'Accept' => 'application/json'])
                        ->get('api/user/index');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

I tried to solved with various ways on internet like read all official documentations and others but I didn't get insight right to solve this. I made `.env.testing`, too.

Any idea, how to solving this problem?

Thank you for your insight.

I tried to solve with these link :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769959/laravel-phpunit-test-with-api-token-authentication](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568924/how-to-pass-bearer-token-to-test-api-using-phpunit-and-liip](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)